# Insignificant impulse response function - does this really mean that there is no effect?

Tags: statistical-significance, vector-autoregression

I estimated a VAR-model and the result was this impulse response function that shows the 95% confidence interval as the red dotted lines. The effect is clearly not significant. But does this mean that there is no effect?

[image]

Comment: There may be a real effect, but too little data (or too much variability in data) to declare 'statistical significance'.

Comment: You almost certainly have some effect. For the effect to be zero means that it is *zero* zero, not just almost zero. What action would you take if the effect is zero as opposed to if it is nonzero?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Sorry @Dave I can't follow your question: What action would you take if the effect is zero as opposed to if it is nonzero?

Comment: Why are you doing this analysis?

Comment: Ah okay I understand. To investigate the effect that public expenditures have on the GDP.

Comment: So what do you do if there is no effect? Small effect? Large effect? Inconclusive?

Comment: I would say inconclusive and would outline to further examine it in future studies